# Raspberry - How can I execute terminal command on start-up and make the terminal visible after login

Tags: raspberry-pi

I created a file below 
`/etc/init.d/superscript` (I made it executable and registered it to the startup)

The file contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/pi/Desktop/
node server.js
```

It is just executing a nodejs file, but the problem is the server.js has to log some text to the console.
Is there a better way of running the server.js file on start-up, so I can see the Terminal after the booting?

Comment: Why not start the server in bashrc and just enable auto login?

Comment: I can do like you said either, but same problem, I cannot see the terminal after login...it's runninh in the background :/

Comment: if you run it from your bashrc after auto login, you will see the output. If you're not, that means something else is going wrong.